# Html Charset Problem (Pound sign coming as a Question mark)

Tags: html

I have a payment form where users will select their country before paying and the options are between us and uk , but when they select UK , my pound sign start appearing like a question mark , i have tried different charset , '£' and also some other ways to solve it , but doesn't seems quite working , is there any way around it and yes to specify these currency sign are manipulating by my jquery file (So is there anything to do with that coz signs are in .js file instead of html).

Looking for some great help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure everything has the same charset (e.g. UTF-8).

- in your HTML-output (via an HTTP-header or a META-tag)
- in your script-files
- (if existing) in your database and also on your database-connection

Comment: Ok lemme try to add charset to my js file